# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when instantiating an inner class

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I have a following problem with an innner class. Here's the code:

```
    public class PGZUserManagerBean {

            // joomla login as separate thread
            private class JoomlaLogin extends Thread {

                private AuthJoomla authJoomla;

                public JoomlaLogin(AuthJoomla authJoomla){
                    this.authJoomla = authJoomla;
                }

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    this.authJoomla.authJoomla();
                }
            }

        public void validateuser(){

            AuthJoomla authJoomla = new AuthJoomla();

            JoomlaLogin joomlaLogin = new JoomlaLogin(authJoomla);
            joomlaLogin.start();

        }

    }
```

I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PGZUserManagerBean$JoomlaLogin` on runtime. I'm using Java 1.6.

Thank you for the help in advance.
al

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is only thrown when trying to load a class that is not known during compile time using Class.forName or similar techniques and the class does not exist.

Comment: Not sure, but could be that your inner class is private and the method using it is public. Should generate a compilation error though, but worth a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you've copied the class files from one place to another (or put them in a jar file) but you've failed to copy/include `PGZUserManagerBean$JoomlaLogin.class`.

Check where you're running the code, and look for the class file that the JVM can't find. It will definitely be in your *compilation* output.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, class file was not copied, but I'm not the one who's copying it. It's Eclipse, because I'm deploying it on Tomcat through Eclipse. So my problem is now, that it's not deployed correctly.